# Pull a hyperlink from a hidden sheet Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to pull a hyperlink from a hidden sheet in excel to be used in combination with an **IF** command, it means there will be 3 arguments.

```
=IF(A24="","",VLOOKUP(A24,'Product Data '!$A$2:$AD$213,19,FALSE))
```

Is this possible?

Please see current formula below. How do I add for the hyperlink to be used in conjunction with the **IF** command as I only want the link to show if specific text is selected.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the `HYPERLINK` from a cell in another cell, you should write it in the `HYPERLINK` formula:

Something like this:

```
=HYPERLINK(IF(1=1,VLOOKUP("www.test.com",'Product Data '!A1:A10,1,0)))
```

The sheet and whether it is hidden or not is irrelevant.

Comment: Hi Thanks, the link  am trying to bring it from is from a different sheet which I am pulling other information from, will this matter?

Comment: @J.Rothwell - nope, the sheet is irrelevant. Just make sure that you notice the space after `'Product Data '`

Comment: Also the link I'm attempting to input has lots of = in it which seems to be conflicting the formula. Basically I want a list of products on one sheet with information which is pulled from one sheet, with in this information i want the data sheet to be linked but only when that specification information is selected via the IF command, it's for specification writing.

Comment: @J.Rothwell - the `=` should not be a conflict because they should be inside `""` like `"www.test.com"` in the example, thus it is ok. A conflict can be `"`, but it is illegal for URL.